# How To Styling search box in Datatable?

Tags: css, dom, datatable

My Searchbox (Now)
[image: My Searchbox (Now)]

I want to styling my checkbox like this
[image: I want to styling my checkbox like this]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's my answer.

but maybe it's not good code.

> HTML CODE

```
<div class="search-form">
  <input type="text" id="search" />
  <span id="search-icon"></span>
</div>
```

> CSS CODE

```
.search-form{
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;

}

#search{
  border: none;
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 5px lightgray;
  border-radius: 40px;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

#search-icon{
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
}
#search-icon::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 10px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: blue;
  left: 10px;
  top: 15px;

}
```

> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XaRmrp`enter code here`